# How to get rid off this error with TCPDF :"TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file"

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to print the output(i.e. value of variable $matter) but I'm getting the error message mentioned above. I did lot of google for it and checked for spaces before and after php tags. But couldn't get the solution. Please help me. Here is my code to print output using tcpdf:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
  require_once("../../includes/application-header.php");

  // Include tcpdf liabrary
  require_once OCN_ROOT."/core/extention/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php";
  require_once OCN_ROOT."/core/extention/tcpdf/tcpdf.php";


    define ('PDF_MARGIN_TOP', 22); 
    define ('PDF_HEADER_TITLE', 'This is Heading');
    define ('PDF_HEADER_STRING', $head_string);
    define ('PDF_CREATOR', PAGE_TITLE); 

    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example');

    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    //set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    //set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    //set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    //set some language-dependent strings
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $matter = <<<EOD
         <h1>HTML Example</h1> 
EOD;

    $pdf->writeHTML($matter, true, false, true, false, '');

    // reset pointer to the last page
    $pdf->lastPage();

    // ---------------------------------------------------------
    ob_flush();
    //Close and output PDF document
    $pdf->Output('example_061.pdf', 'I');

    //============================================================+
    // END OF FILE                                                
    //============================================================+
?>
```

Comment: Check if your script is saved as UTF-8 with a BOM. If so, save it without a BOM (it should be a setting in your editor). If this is the case, you will see `0xFF 0xEF` bytes output at the very top of the response. Do this for all scripts involved, including the ones you are `require()`ing and any scripts that they `include()`/`require()`.

Comment: @DaveRandom. I'm using eclipse Helios, I don't found any setting for BOM.

Comment: how is the result page look alike...?

Comment: @user1711126. The blank page appears with error message:
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

Comment: @Sushil Add this code on the line before the error, and report back with the output: `headers_sent($_file, $_line); echo "Headers send in $_file on line $_line<br>\n";`

Comment: FWIW, I don't see why this is closed as Too Localized.  Helped me a lot thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try instead of `ob_flush();` with `ob_end_clean();`

Comment: Well spotted. This is probably the answer.